# update all rows after insertion in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am working with mysql and I have a table with the following structure (a summary):

```
CREATE TABLE `costs` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `utility` DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tax` DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

where the active field defaults to 1 when inserting, then i would like when saving a new record all other rows update the active field as 0, so i try to create a trigger for this but i am getting a mysql error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_costs_insert AFTER INSERT ON costs FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE costs SET active = 0 WHERE id <> NEW.id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I think it is not possible to do this, so how can I update these rows?

Comment: Why you even need this active column if you always want your last row to be active?
Updating each row after each insert is a heavy cost, so you can cache the active row id.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon. That's a typical limitation in SQL, that is mainly meant to prevent infinite loop on invokation (a query fires a trigger, that executes a query, that fires the trigger, and so on).

Here, instead of actually storing this derived information, I would actually recommend using a view that computes the column on the fly when queried.

If you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
create view costs_view as
select 
    id, 
    utility, 
    tax, 
    row_number() over(order by id desc) = 1 active,
    created_at,
    updated_at
from costs
```

In earlier versions:

```
create view costs_view as
select 
    id, 
    utility, 
    tax, 
    id = (select max(id) from costs) active,
    created_at,
    updated_at
from costs
```

This gives you an always up-to-date column, that you just don't need to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the most recent row, then you can use:

```
select c.*
from costs c
order by id desc   -- or created_at
limit 1;
```

This will work in a view.

More often, the situation is that you have one active *per* something -- such as a "utility" or whatever.  In that case, you can use a secondary table to store one row per "something" along with the id of the active account.  The trigger can set this idea.

In your case, you have only one active row in the `costs` table, so a secondary table might be considered overkill.  You can easily get the current active value using the above query.